# Moviepy write videofile extremely slow in docker compared to native

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, docker, aws-lambda, moviepy

I am running docker locally with dockerfile created for AWS LAMBDA.
Moviepy performance in writing videofiles causes api request to time out, it is atleast 10x slower than running natively.

I tried increasing cpu and memory resources but performance is still the same

```
final_clip.write_videofile(output_file_path, codec="libx264", audio_codec="aac", fps=24, threads=8)
```

Comment: How long did it take before it timed-out?

Comment: Docker request times out after 300s

Comment: Did you try increasing the timeout? It can go up to 15 minutes. Where does the `output_file_path` point to -- is it going to the `/tmp/` directory? Does it _always_ timeout? Have you tried it with a smaller file to see if it works?

Comment: How to increase the timeout

Comment: In the AWS Lambda console, open the function, go to the **Configuration** tab. The **Timeout** setting is in the **General Configuration** section.